# Unexpected result using regular expressions

Tags: javascript

Why is `result` false? Expecting it to be `true`.

```js
string = "pain";

regexp = /PAINPAIN/i;

result = regexp.test(string);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're looking for `painpain` inside of `pain`, not the other way round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result is false because your regex is wrong. Consider below example. You are looking *PAINPAIN* inside *pain*.

```js
string = "painpain";

regexp = /PAIN/i;

result = regexp.test(string);

console.log(result);
```